# Missing the explorer pane in bigquary

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to bigquary and I am using sandbox lately whenever I open bigquary the explorer pane is not visible. How can I bring the explorer pane back.

I tried to logout and login-that doesn't solve it. please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me after I had gone into full screen mode with the query I was working on. Once I took my window off of full screen, I no longer had my explorer pane and couldn't figure out to get it back. Eventually, I toggled the full screen option (on the top right) and it came back. Maybe try that?

Hope that helped!